# Integral of $\,\tan^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-integrals

I want to evaluate $\,\displaystyle I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm dx$.
I proved that $\,I_{n}+I_{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\,,\,$ where $I_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.
From that I found that (it's easy to prove by induction) $$I_{n}=(-1)^{n} \frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2(n-k)+1}$$ My question is, is there any way to telescope that sum ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are the remainders of [this series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) I might be remembering wrong, but I think the partial sums of that series cannot be written as a fixed sum of hypergeometric terms.  You could [express it in terms of other special functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%282*k%2B1%29+from+k%3D0+to+k%3Dn+) Whether that is any more useful than the original expression or not depends on the final goal.

Comment: Your formula for $I_n - I_{n-1}$ is wrong.

Comment: $I_{n}-I_{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{2n-1}$ should be $I_{n}+I_{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{2n-1}$.

Comment: Bakugany, you should write $\;I_n+I_{n-1}=\dfrac1{2n-1}\;$ instead of $\;I_n-I_{n-1}=\dfrac1{2n-1}\;$ which is wrong.

Comment: I think that it would be better to write your (correct) formula for $I_n$ in the following way :$$I_n=(-1)^n\left[\dfrac{\pi}4-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac1{2k-1}\right]$$ So we can get that $$I_n=(-1)^n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\dfrac1{2k-1}$$ that is $$I_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(-1)^{k-n+1}\dfrac1{2k-1}$$ or also $$I_n=\sum_{h=1}^\infty(-1)^{h+1}\dfrac1{2(n+h)-1}$$

Comment: [Does this help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588784/indefinite-integral-of-tanxp-q/4591056#4591056)